# Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\is_object()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\is_object() in D:\WorkspaceAll\cmf\sandbox\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader.php on line 240`

When I'm trying to install CMF sandbox on windows localhost. How can this be possible? Could anybody help me an explaination for this?

This is the function:

```
public static function classExists($className)
    {
        if (class_exists($className, false) || interface_exists($className, false)) {
            return true;
        }
        foreach (spl_autoload_functions() as $loader) {
            if (is_array($loader)) { // array(???, ???)
                if (is_object($loader[0])) {
                    if ($loader[0] instanceof ClassLoader) { // array($obj, 'methodName')
                        if ($loader[0]->canLoadClass($className)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else if ($loader[0]->{$loader[1]}($className)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else if ($loader[0]::$loader[1]($className)) { // array('ClassName', 'methodName')
                    return true;
                }
            } else if ($loader instanceof \Closure) { // function($className) {..}
                if ($loader($className)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (is_string($loader) && $loader($className)) { // "MyClass::loadClass"
                return true;
            }

            if (class_exists($className, false) || interface_exists($className, false)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What version of PHP? It looks like it's not [falling back to the global namespace for undefined functions](http://php.net/manual/language.namespaces.fallback.php) but only for `is_object`.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.4.22 and same thing happens when I change to 5.4.23. It's weird, and only happen on Windows

Comment: check that you have PDO and the desired drivers installed or not

Comment: If you are running APC, disable it and try again. Same or different result?

Comment: Yes, Turn off APC and it works, turn on again it still works until now. I dont know why.

Comment: APC caches your code in it`s own format. When you "restart" it, cache are regenerated with "currect data".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not claiming this is an answer to your problem, but my rep will not allow me to add a comment to ask you this.
Are you writing in visual studio? I had a similar error for a MVC project and luckily, all I had to do was clean solution in VS2010 and it worked!

Comment: Hi, It was resolved & I don't use Visual Studio to code PHP :). This is very rare problem, I think.